# HTML Table with dates as header columns using angular

Tags: angularjs

I have to generate a table from JSON data in angular, where the table should have the structure like [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLsb166r/). Where the table should have columns till the no. of days in a month where month is given as input, Now the data corresponding to that student on that particular date should be displayed in each row.

Sample json is:

```
{ 

        "start_date":"2016-01-01 9:30:00",   
        "end_date":"2016-01-01 17:00:00",  
        "details":"Logged",        
        "name":"XXX"
},
{ 

        "start_date":"2016-03-02 10:30:00",   
        "end_date":"2016-03-02 12:00:00",  
        "details":"Logged",        
        "name":"XXX"
    },
    { 

        "start_date":"2016-03-03 10:30:00",   
        "end_date":"2016-03-03 12:00:00",  
        "details":"Logged",        
        "ename":"XXX"
}
```

code

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Select student to get data :
<input type="text" value="" ng-model="search" id="search"/>
<select id="monthSel" ng-model="selMonth">
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option selected="selected" value="03" >March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<table border="1">
    <tr >
        <th>Name</th>
        <th ng-repeat="data in jsonData | FilterByMonth:selMonth">{{data.start_date|dateFormat}}</th>

    </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="stud in students| filter:search">
      <td>{{stud}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat="data in jsonData |filter:{ename:search} | FilterByMonth:selMonth ">{{data.start_date|time}}  {{data.end_date|time}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
<script>
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

controller

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
      $scope.events = [];
      $scope.scheduler = { date : new Date() };

     $http.get("data.json")
        .success(function(response) {

            $scope.jsonData = response;
            $scope.students= $scope.jsonData.map(function(a) {return a.ename;});;
            $scope.students= $scope.students.reduce(function(a,b){if(a.indexOf(b)<0)a.push(b);return a;},[]);

        }).error(function(response){
            alert("error"+angular.toJson(response));
        });
    });

    app.filter('dateFormat', function($filter)
    {
     return function(input)
     {
      if(input == null){ return ""; } 

      var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd/MM/yyyy');

      return _date.toUpperCase();

     };
    });

    app.filter('time', function($filter)
    {
     return function(input)
     {
      if(input == null){ return ""; } 

      var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'HH:mm:ss');

      return _date.toUpperCase();

     };
    });



 app.filter('FilterByMonth', function ($filter) {
      return function (items, month) {
        var filtered = [];
        // var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          var item = items[i];
        var _date =  new Date(item.start_date);

          if ( _date.getMonth()+1 == month) { 
            filtered.push(item);
          }
        }
        return filtered;
      };
    });
```

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: <table border="1">
    <tr >
        <th>Name</th>
  <th ng-repeat="data in jsonData">{{data.start_date|dateFormat}}</th>
        
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="stud in students | filter:search">
   <td>{{stud}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="data in jsonData ">{{data.start_date|time}}  {{data.end_date|time}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>  The above code just adds the columns as whatever is in the json start date.I thought of implementing it using filter if i select march month from dropdown then it has to fetch the start dates for march and display in the table but problem is row data is not properly mapped

Comment: Please add the code to the question, in a comment it's unreadable...

Comment: And please add the code you use to populate `var students`...

Comment: Added the code, its almost done , what i am i looking for if i give name and select month i am getting headers created dynamically and data is populated in the rows, now the problem is if i enter a student who doesnt have entry from 1 to 30 but has entry only in 31st then that value should be displayed in last column currently it is displaying in first column

Comment: I yet don't see code that populates `students`... And... May I suggest you to post a jsfiddle? You'd have more probabilities to get an useful answer...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qLsb166r/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the td's :

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Select student to get data :
<input type="text" value="" ng-model="search" id="search"/>
<select id="monthSel" ng-model="selMonth">
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option selected="selected" value="03" >March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<table border="1">
   <tr ng-repeat="stud in students| filter:search">
     <td data-title="{{data.start_date}}">{{stud}}</td>
     <td data-title="{{data.start_date}}" ng-repeat="data in jsonData |filter:{ename:search} | FilterByMonth:selMonth ">{{data.start_date|time}}  {{data.end_date|time}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
</script>
</body>
```

Do it with the **data-title**, it will add automatically the **th** with the value that you want, if it dont work, inject **ngTable**, maybe you'll need it to run that code, here you have a full example --> [ngTable Example](http://ng-table.com/#/intro/demo-real-world)

Comment: Use ngTable to make the table better, you need to use it to use data-title in the <td>, here you can find a basic example --> http://ng-table.com/#/intro/demo-real-world just see how it works, is not hard ;P